# GitLab oauth2 Laravel "{"message":"401 Unauthorized"}"

Tags: php, laravel

My gitLab controller. Links taken from the documentation. After submitting the form
returns an error "{"message":"401 Unauthorized"}" . Token is coming, but i want to
get username and email.

### My gitLab controller

```
    public function callback(Request $request)
   {
        $response = Http::withHeaders(['Accept' => 'application/json'])
           ->asForm()
           ->post('https://gitlab.com/oauth/token',[
               'client_id' => config('oauth.gitlab.client_id'),
               'client_secret' => config('oauth.gitlab.client_secret'),
               'code' => $request->get('code'),
               'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
               'redirect_uri' => config('oauth.gitlab.callback_uri'),
           ]);
       $token = $response['access_token'];
       

       $response = Http::withHeaders(['Authorization' => 'token ' . $token])
           ->get('https://gitlab.com/api/v4/user');
```

also link https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects is work success

```
       dd($response->body());
      }
```

after checking I get an error 401. I don't understand why.

### ** My class GitlabServices**

```
      public static function link(): string {
    $params = [
        'response_type' => 'code',
        'client_id' => config('oauth.gitlab.client_id'),
        'redirect_uri' => config('oauth.gitlab.callback_uri'),
        'scope' => 'read_user openid'
    ];

    return 'https://gitlab.com/oauth/authorize?' . http_build_query($params);
}
  
   client_id, secret, redirect_uri store in .env
```

Comment: Missing a space in `'token' . $token`: `'token ' . $token`

Comment: you need a space " " between the "token" and the $token like `$response = Http::withHeaders(['Authorization' => 'token ' . $token])`

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it but the problem steel have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding 'token_type' to the request headers helped me

```
 $token = $response->json('access_token');
 $tokenType = $response->json('token_type');

 $response = Http::withHeaders(['Authorization' => $tokenType . ' ' . $token])
       ->get('https://gitlab.com/api/v4/user');
```

The connection was successful and I received all the necessary information after making above mentioned changes.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you getting 401 in response. Check if the token privileges to request data.
Probably:

1. Token  is not attached with request.
2. Token don't have privileges.